# Obtain return type of a function using its name and NLP using python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

Let's say i have a string which is a function name:

```
nameString = "return_list_of_apples"
#or
nameString = "return_apples_list"
```

I already can extract all the words in the names using nltk and a function that i have like:

```
nameString = "return_list_of_apples"
wordsList = words_to_list(nameString)
print(wordsList)
>> ['return', 'list', 'of', 'apples']
```

How can i obtain return type of function using its name? in this example list.
is there any python module for it?
I think it's in NLP field.

Comment: Your question is not clear, could you give an example to better-explain your idea?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to determine a Python function's return type because the nature of Python is such that any one function could return a multitude of different data types

Comment: @Anwarvic Lets say i have a function return_somthing_list(). It's clear from it's name that this function returns a list. or a function named get_tuple_of_something() returns a tuple. i want to obtain the return type from the function name.

Comment: @BrutusForcus That's the point. i want to do this in order to determine if the function name is in contrast with it's actual return type or not. If it is, it's a "Linguistic antipattern".